# Dispatch an event if any error is occurred in Joomla

Tags: php, joomla, error-handling, joomla3.0, dispatchevent

Is there any way to dispatch an event and call a method when an error is occurred in joomla same as Zend ? I want to log those error in log file. I want to use a single method to catch every error. is it possible ?

Is there any other way to do this except JError, Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

To log errors to a file, you can use the following:

```
jimport('joomla.log.log');

// Log errors to specific file.
JLog::addLogger(
   array(
      'text_file' => 'mod_mymodule.errors.php'
   ),
   JLog::ALL,
   'mod_mymodule'
);
```

This will create the following and store all error there:

```
root/logs/mod_mymodule.errors.php
```

You can of course change **mod_mymodule** to whatever you wish.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Lodder. Can we make a generic logger class that will log the error of every module and component?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right you can use [JError](http://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JError.html) class to get this done. You can raise error and handle them.

Comment: JError is deprecated though it is still used lots and lots of places where the switch to exceptions or messages has not been made.